# Deploy default angular application on azure from github gives error

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, npm, deployment

I have created a basic angular application.
the source code is at https://github.com/devang-zala-sa/azure1

The azure web app URL is http://azuret01.azurewebsites.net/

---

**Update**
@Milo provided right direction, with that I was able to get rid of the errors.

Now there is no error, and deployment is successful, but still I cant access http://azuret01.azurewebsites.net/.

More details.
Success in deployment.
[image: Success in deployment]

Deployment details
[image: Deployment details]

Generating Deployment Script [View Log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxceJLa2ukYWRG9vaTc3dENBNmc)

Running Deployment Command [View Log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxceJLa2ukYWbVJXOEdSdWdPRVk)

Actual Deplyement script, from location [D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxceJLa2ukYWVmFDSzRHZWVqems) using kudu.

Still I can't access this default Angular App, please help.

---

I want to create a web application in azure.

I have created web application with below commands in azure portal.

```
az group create --name testrg --location "East US" testrg   AZUREACCOUNT
az appservice plan create --name testas --resource-group testrg --sku FREE
az webapp create --name azuret01 --resource-group testrg --plan testas.
```

I have connected the github repo with azure.
please find the steps I have followed.

[image]

Now it shows the error.

[image]

Now, I have gone a step further.
[image]

When I visit the published URL aka https://azuret01.azurewebsites.net/[image]

Please find the [logfile](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxceJLa2ukYWdFktVExSWEdXZVk)  for error, please find few of them as bullets for easy reference.

- Looking for app.js/server.js under site root.
- Invalid start-up command "ng serve" in package.json. Please use the format "node ".
- Missing server.js/app.js files, web.config is not generated
- The package.json file does not specify node.js engine version constraints.
- The node.js application will run with the default node.js version 0.10.40.
- Selected npm version 1.4.28
- npm ERR! 404 Not Found
- npm ERR! 404
- npm ERR! 404 'angular/http' is not in the npm registry.
- npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
- Failed exitCode=1, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\0.10.40\node.exe" "D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\1.4.28\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" install --production
- npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'azure1'
- An error has occurred during web site deployment.
- npm ERR! 404

I have spent quite a lot time on deploying my actual angular app in azure, but that was not successful, so I did try with this minimal approach and even this does not works.

Has anyone encountered this, or can anyone guide me what I am doing wrong?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You could try specifying a higher version of node to run. It's saying it's running `1.4.28`, version I have currently is `5.3.0`..

Comment: Can you please guide me, where I can change that.
I have 4.2.0 version in my local system.

Comment: Take a look at this [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34746480/upgrading-node-on-an-azure-website/39422959#39422959)

Comment: I have followed it, now there is another set of errors, I am working on it.

if I get success in solving this, I will post my answer, else will add more details in question.

but thanks for the tip to upgrade version @Milo, it did help.

Comment: @Milo, I have updated my answer, now I dont have any errors, still I cant access the site, see if you can provide any help.

Comment: You can check this [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33835172/azure-you-do-not-have-permission-to-view-this-directory-or-page) and check this [tutorial](https://johnpapa.net/deploy-angular-to-azure-vsts-angular-cli/) to further troubleshoot

Comment: @Milo, those links leads me to Node js application while my application is in Angular JS.

We don't have web.config and server.js in default Angualr app.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need to build your angular project after deploying the source code to Azure.

1. Add `"postinstall": "npm run build"` script to `scripts` section from the `package.json` as below:

   ```
   "scripts": {
       "ng": "ng",
       "start": "ng serve",
       "build": "ng build --prod",
       "test": "ng test",
       "lint": "ng lint",
       "e2e": "ng e2e",
       "postinstall": "npm run build"
   },
   ```

   Then commit this change and push it to your GitHub repo. This will build your app and places it into the `dist/` directory after all npm packages are installed.
2. Change virtual directory from `site\wwwroot` to `site\wwwroot\dist` in the **Application settings** blade via [Azure portal](http://portal.azure.com).

   [image]

Comment: you are life savor for me.

Thanks a lot for this help.

Comment: the virtual applications and directories part saved me. Thanks!

Comment: I have spent countless hours trying to deploy my VueJS App on Azure, the virtual directory tip solved it for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Inside the virtual applications and directories config section I also have the option "Application or directory", which one should I choose?
It's not visible in your screenshot unfortunately.